# how to see underlying code in stats library

Tags: r

I would like to see the source code for the TUKEY HSD test

when I do this
getAnywhere("stats::TukeyHSD")

```
no object named ‘stats::TukeyHSD’ was found
```

and when I try getAnywhere("TukeyHSD")

I get the results

```
 single object matching ‘TukeyHSD’ was found
It was found in the following places
  package:stats
  namespace:stats
with value

function (x, which, ordered = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95, ...) 
UseMethod("TukeyHSD")
<bytecode: 0x000000000b364580>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

but where can I see the code?

Thank you.

Comment: Following the chain in that answer, I landed at `getAnywhere("TukeyHSD.aov")`

Comment: @Frank I had closed this as a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19226816/324364) which is a better duplicate, but it was mysteriously reopened.

Comment: @joran http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38664009/revisions

Comment: @Frank Sigh. Now it all makes sense.